# ios: Animating UIControl with CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift) and trying to make a slider.

I have a Slide class:

```
class YDSlider: UIControl {

    var value = 0.0
...
```

And it has a sublayer with gradient to show the progress (just like a tutorial). I'd like to implement a `func setValue(value: Double, animated: Bool)` function, but I don't understand how to animate changes. My current approach is not working:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay:1.0, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.value = value

        }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the source of your class, it will be difficult to help you but as far as I can see in the tutorial, the slider is designed with UIViews, CALayers and with the drawRect method.

So depending on the kind of elements of your slider you want to animate, you will have to use UIView animateions and for CoreAnimation.
If you need to animate parts designed with the drawRect method, this will be trickier and you will have to redraw manually the parts for each animation frame.

Comment: My sublayers are created with drawRect method. What should I do in that case?